# Using multiple versions of boost

Tags: c++, mongodb, visual-c++, boost, linker-errors

I have a project which uses the MongoDB C++ driver. As I'm on WinXP I have to use MongoDB 2.0, which uses Boost 1.42.
However my application uses Boost 1.48.

When I statically link the MongoDB driver and build my application I get a LNK1104 linker error that libboost_system-vc100-md-gd-1_42.lib is missing.
When I add this library in addition to the in the app required 1.48 library version, I get a LNK2005 "boost::system::throws already defined" linker error.

Is there a way to use Boost 1.42 in my static library for MongoDB and use Boost 1.48 in my application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using concurrently 2 versions of boost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907882/using-concurrently-2-versions-of-boost)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split your build process: first compile the MongDB C++ driver into a separate .lib while linking against Boost 1.42.0 Then in a second step you compile your own application, linking against the MongoDB library and Boost 1.48.0. This should work as long as the MongDB .lib does not expose any of the boost functions such as `boost::system::throws`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836875/creating-library-with-backward-compatible-abi-that-uses-boost) for how to limit the public interface from exposing Boost symbols.

Alternatively, try compiling your entire application with only a single Boost version (either 1.42 or 1.48).

Comment: I do compile the driver into a separate lib, however this issue still occurs.

Comment: @Simon see updated answer for how to deal with leaking Boost symbols from other .libs

Comment: I was trying to avoid changing whole application to same Boost version, but so far seems to be the only solution.

Comment: I sympathize, it would be great if Mongo got compatible with the latest Boost

Comment: Well, they do with 2.2 or 2.4. However with XP you can only use 2.0